# Java how to get context in PageAdapter in getCount()?

Tags: java, android

I'm working on a home replacement app and I need to get the context to access shared preferences and get the number of screens my app should have to use it on getCount().

I've banging my head against the wall for the last few hours but I cannot figure out how to get the context before getCount() is fired.

This is my code:

```
public class MyPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
    public Context context;

    public int getCount() {
        return 5;
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(View container, int position) {
        Context context = container.getContext();
    }
```

I'm getting the context on instatiateItem but instatiateItem runs after getCount(), is there a way to get the context directly on the pageAdapter? Or how can I run getContext() before getCount() is fired?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why dont you pass the `Context` in the constructor of the `MyPagerAdapter`? 
Create the constructor of `MyPagerAdapter` as follows:

```
public class MyPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter
    {
        public Context  context;

        MyPagerAdapter(Context context)
        {
            this.context = context;
        }

        public int getCount()
        {
            return 5;
        }

    }
```

And in your activity you should write initialize the PagerAdapter as

```
MyPagerAdapter adapter = new MyPagerAdapter(this);
```

Comment: I changed MyPageAdapter to this but I got this errors: `- Syntax error on token "(", { expected
 - Syntax error, insert ";" to complete 
  ClassBodyDeclarations
 - Syntax error, insert "}" to complete Block`

Comment: I tried `public class MyPagerAdapter(Context context) extends PagerAdapter {` and `public class MyPagerAdapter(Context context) {` both created similar errors. As there is an upvote I suppose the answer is right, what am I doing wrong then?

Comment: now I'm getting an error on my mainActivity next to `MyPagerAdapter adapter = new MyPagerAdapter();`, the error says "The constructor MyPagerAdapter() is undefined" any idea why this may happen?